# How configure Bind (DNS) server to respond internet and intranet?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, internet, internal-dns

I want to know how to configure bind server, if IP is internal, respond the `internal A Record` of server and if IP is external the second  A record is provided.

For example:

```
MYSERVER  A  30  10.10.9.158   (intranet) 
MYSERVER A  30 176.70.70.78   (internet)
```

If I am out of country consider it internet and if I am inside country consider  it as intranet.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a split configuration.  Your external configuration should not offer recursive look-ups.  Search for `bind split views` for more details.

In short form, you will need to:

- Define an ACL for your internal network.
- Create separate views for the internal network and the external network.
- Create separate zone files for the internal network and the external network.
- Ensure the external view does not offer recursion.